# Adding DT R packages prevents Docker from running

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dt

I use Docker to run Shiny app, and I install some R packages in the Dockerfile (here is the portion of the Dockerfile, I omitted some lines, marking it with <...>):

```
FROM r-base:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -t unstable \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    make \
    git \
    gcc \
    <...>
    R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')" && \
    R -e "install.packages(c('ada','bsplus','caret','ddalpha','diptest','doMC','dplyr','e1071','evtree','fastAdaboost','foreach','GGally','ggplot2','gridExtra','iterators','kernlab','lattice','markdown','MASS','mboost','nnet','optparse','partykit','plyr','pROC','PRROC','randomForest','recipes','reshape2','RSNNS','scales','shinyBS','shinyFiles','shinythemes'))"
```

This works fine. But if I add one more R package (DT), the container still builds fine (and I can see that the package gets installed properly) but when I try to run the container I get:

```
Loading required package: shiny
Error in dir.exists(lib) : invalid filename argument
Calls: <Anonymous> ... load_libraries -> get_package -> install.packages -> dir.exists
Execution halted
```

This error is not informative at all and I can't figure out what possibly can be wrong. I will appreciate any ideas! Thank you.

Comment: Does it work locally (ie, outside of a container)?

Comment: @HongOoi Yes, it does!